# process socket data that ends with a line break

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sockets, tcp

What is the best approach to process a socket connection where I need var `data` to end with a line break `\n`? 
I'm using the code below but sometimes the `tcp` packets get **chunked** and it takes a long time to match `data.endswith("\n")`.
I've also tried other approaches, like saving the last line if it doesn't end with `\n` and append it to `data`on the next loop. but this also doesn't work because multiple packets get chunked and the 1st and 2nd part don't match.
I've no control over the other end, it basically sends multiple lines that end in `\r\n`.

Any suggestion will be welcome, as I don't have much knowledge on socket connections.

```
def receive_bar_updates(s):
    global all_bars
    data = ''
    buffer_size = 4096
    while True:
        data += s.recv(buffer_size)
        if not data.endswith("\n"):
            continue
        lines = data.split("\n")
        lines = filter(None, lines)
        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith("BH") or line.startswith("BC"):
                symbol = str(line.split(",")[1])
                all_bars[symbol].append(line)
                y = Thread(target=proccess_bars, kwargs={'symbol': symbol})
                y.start()
        data = ""
```

Example of "*normal*" `data`:

```
line1\r\n
line2\r\n
line3\r\n
```

Example of **chunked** `data`:

```
line1\r\n
line2\r\n
lin
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a raw input that you want to process as line, the io module is your friend because it will do the low level assembling of packets in lines.

You could use:

```
class SocketIO(io.RawIOBase):
    def __init__(self, sock):
        self.sock = sock
    def read(self, sz=-1):
        if (sz == -1): sz=0x7FFFFFFF
        return self.sock.recv(sz)
    def seekable(self):
        return False
```

It is more robust than `endswith('\n')` because if one packet contains an embedded newline (`'ab\ncd'`), the io module will correctly process it. Your code could become:

```
def receive_bar_updates(s):
    global all_bars
    data = ''
    buffer_size = 4096
    fd = SocketIO(s)  # fd can be used as an input file object

    for line in fd:
        if should_be_rejected_by_filter(line): continue # do not know what filter does...
        if line.startswith("BH") or line.startswith("BC"):
            symbol = str(line.split(",")[1])
            all_bars[symbol].append(line)
            y = Thread(target=proccess_bars, kwargs={'symbol': symbol})
            y.start()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm receiving "***raw input***", I've updated the question with some examples of the input `data`. The `filter` removes empty entries on the list.

Comment: The packets don't contain embed new lines characters, just a bunch of lines ending in `\r\n` and I need to process the `data` **only** if the last line is complete (ending in `\n`), otherwise I'll be randomly losing the last lines because they're incomplete.

Comment: @PedroLobito: TCP is a stream protocol. That means that depending of the different equipements  (switches, routers, gateways), packets may be splitted in smaller pieces or rearranged in larger ones. Even if the sender only send packets ending with a newline, 2 or more of those packets could be assembled in one single larger packet. And that packet will contain embedded newlines.

Comment: @PedroLobito: and IOBase will correctly reassamble *chunks* in on line is splitted into 2 different packets.

Comment: That's great, I didn't know it could do that. I can only test this on a real-time environment,  which will be possible tomorrow. I'll post the results after. tks!

Comment: I noticed you've removed the `while` loop but I need it to continue processing more lines, this will go on during 10 hours without stop, how'd achieve this without the loop ?

Comment: @PedroLobito: Unless the connection is reset, the `for line in fd` **is** the loop.

Comment: Your answer nailed it, appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Use [socket.socket.makefile()](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/socket.html?highlight=listen#socket.socket.makefile) to wrap the socket in a class that implenents [Text I/O](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/io.html?highlight=textio#text-i-o).  It handles buffering, converting between bytes and strings, and lets you iterate over lines.  Remember to flush any writes.

Example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import socket, threading, time


def client(addr):
    with socket.create_connection(addr) as conn:
        conn.sendall(b'aaa')
        time.sleep(1)
        conn.sendall(b'bbb\n')
        time.sleep(1)
        conn.sendall(b'cccddd\n')
        time.sleep(1)
        conn.sendall(b'eeefff')
        time.sleep(1)
        conn.sendall(b'\n')
        conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
        response = conn.recv(1024)
        print('client got %r' % (response,))


def main():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0) as listen_socket:
        listen_socket.bind(('localhost', 0))
        listen_socket.listen(1)
        addr = listen_socket.getsockname()
        threading.Thread(target=client, args=(addr,)).start()
        conn, _addr = listen_socket.accept()
        conn_file = conn.makefile(mode='rw', encoding='utf-8')
        for request in conn_file:
            print('server got %r' % (request,))
        conn_file.write('response1\n')
        conn_file.flush()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
$ ./example.py
server got 'aaabbb\n'
server got 'cccddd\n'
server got 'eeefff\n'
client got b'response1\n'
$
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this code, but it should work:

```
def receive_bar_updates(s):
    global all_bars
    data = ''
    buf = ''
    buffer_size = 4096
    while True:
        if not "\r\n" in data:  # skip recv if we already have another line buffered.
            data += s.recv(buffer_size)
        if not "\r\n" in data:
            continue
        i = data.rfind("\r\n")
        data, buf = data[:i+2], data[i+2:]
        lines = data.split("\r\n")
        lines = filter(None, lines)
        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith("BH") or line.startswith("BC"):
                symbol = str(line.split(",")[1])
                all_bars[symbol].append(line)
                y = Thread(target=proccess_bars, kwargs={'symbol': symbol})
                y.start()
        data = buf
```

**Edit:** Forgot to mention, i only modified the code for receiving the data, i have no idea what the rest of the function (starting with `lines = data.split("\n")`) is for.

**Edit 2:** Now uses "\r\n" for linebreaks instead of "\n".

**Edit 3:** Fixed an issue.

Comment: The code gets stuck on `if not "\n" in data:
            continue` the rest of the code works normally.

Comment: Does the received string allways contain a "\n"? (except when the data is "chunked")

Comment: `data` **needs** to **end** with `\n` **not** only containing `\n`.

Comment: But the chunked data does not end with a `\n`. So this code instead checks with `in` to "repair" the data with the next chunk of data. BTW, I just found another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you accepting different connections? Or is it one stream of data, split up by `\r\n`'s?

When accepting multiple connections you'd wait for a connection with `s.accept()` and then process all its data. When you have all of the packet, process its data, and wait for the next connection. 
What you do then depends on what the structure of each packet would be.
(Example: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication)

If instead you are consuming a stream of data, you should probably process each 'line' you find in a separate thread, while you keep consuming on another.

**Edit:**
So, if I have your situation correct; one connection, the data being a string broken up by `\r\n`, ending with a `\n`. The data however does not correspond to what you are expecting, instead looping infinitely waiting for a `\n`.

The socket interface, as I understand it, ends with an empty data result. So the last buffer might have ended with a `\n`, but then just continued getting `None` objects, trying to find another `\n`.

Instead, try adding this:

```
if not data:
    break
```

Full code:

```
def receive_bar_updates(s):
    global all_bars
    data = ''
    buffer_size = 4096
    while True:
        data += s.recv(buffer_size)
        if not data:
            break
        if not data.endswith("\n"):
            continue
        lines = data.split("\n")
        lines = filter(None, lines)
        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith("BH") or line.startswith("BC"):
                symbol = str(line.split(",")[1])
                all_bars[symbol].append(line)
                y = Thread(target=proccess_bars, kwargs={'symbol': symbol})
                y.start()
        data = ""
```

**Edit2: Oops, wrong code**

Comment: I'm accepting just one connection, the input data is a group of lines ending  with `\r\n`, after making sure the last line ends in `\n`, I split the lines. The problem is the code gets stuck on  `if not "\n" in data: continue` and it loops for a long time until it gets a match.

Comment: The code is looping, looking for a `\n` in an endless stream of None objects. I hope my edit helps.

Comment: `data` **needs** to **end** with `\n` **not** only containing `\n`.

Comment: Yes, but a None object will never end with `\n`. After the actual situation you are looking for, it will loop again, only find `None` objects and adding them to the now empty `data` object So when you find a `None` object, stop looking, you're done. As you say, the packets might be chunked. Immediately after accepting the first connection, you have to be ready to get the next chunk, if there is one. Process the newly accepted connection in a thread, work with the data you get, and put what you have left in a buffer for the next chunk to use.

Answer (score -1):

You basically seem to want to read lines from the socket. Maybe you're better off not using low level `recv` calls but just use `sock.makefile()` and treat the result as a regular file where you can read lines from: `from line in sfile: ...`

That leaves the delay/chunk issue. This is likely to be caused by [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) on the sending side. Try disabling that:

```
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
```