# Python 2.7 recv from socket until newline

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, tcp

I get data over tcp ip connection and have to read it. My problem is that I don't not know the length, just that there is "\n" at the end.

```
text = ""
while True:
    data = s.recv(1)
    text += data
    if data == "\n":
        break
return text
```

Using this code the functionality is ok, but it is to slow for my application (the "if" seems to be the slow part).  Maybe about half a second I have to wait and I just get between 3 and 8 bytes.

So is it possible to get that done faster?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: well bad formating by my side sorry - retrieving between 3 and 8 bytes is correct but i dont know if there come 3,4,5,6,7 or 8 bytes so i have to check for "\n" and this check is very slow - i am searching for a faster check method

Comment: It is not only formatting. The point is: **minimal complete** input. That one line of code doesn't tell us what your code is doing in the end. As you mainly **describe** that. Simple: more code helps to get better feedback.

Comment: well there is not much more than "import socket" and TCP_IP = '192.168.0.61'
TCP_PORT = 1414


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.settimeout(2.0)

Comment: Dont put stuff into comments. **EDIT** your question. And please use that *preview* functionality, and all that HELP explaining how to use our markdown language to properly format/indent your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [process socket data that ends with a line break](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42987650/process-socket-data-that-ends-with-a-line-break)