# python socket connection fail to receive full message

Tags: sockets, buffer, python-sockets

I use the following code to receive data and dump to a file. But when the characters are sent more than 1500 it is failing to receive full message hence json is not proper in the file. This is happening inconsistantly i.e sometimes full mussage is received and sometime it is failed.

But theis issue doesn't happen when at the same time if we use logstash as receiver.

Receiver script:

```
s.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print('Got connection from', addr)
    json_data = c.recv(16384).decode() # Increasing this doesn't help
    json_dump = json.dumps(json_data)  

    if os.path.exists(destination_file):
        append_write = 'a'  # append if already exists
    else:
        append_write = 'w'  # make a new file if not
    dump_file = open(destination_file, append_write)
    dump_file.write(json_dump + '\n')
    dump_file.close()

    c.send(b'SUCCESS')
    c.close()
```

Sender Script

```
def send_data(socket_conn, data_stream):
    try:
        json_data = JSONEncoder().encode(data_stream)
        json_data = json_data
        socket_conn.send(json_data.encode())
        socket_conn.send(b'\n')
        socket_conn.close()
        return True
    except socket.error as msg:
        logging.error(msg, exc_info=True)
        return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  json_data = c.recv(16384).decode() # Increasing this doesn't help
```

TCP is a stream protocol and not a message protocol. There is no guarantee that if the sender sends all the data with a single `send` that they can be received with a single `recv`.

If the peer is sending only a single JSON and then closing the connection the recipient might simply `recv` until no more data are available (`recv` returns empty message) and concatenate the parts:

```
 data = b''
 while True:
     buf = c.recv(16384)
     if not buf:
         break
     data = data + buf
 json_data = data.decode()
```

If instead the peer is sending multiple "messages" then there must be some message indicator at the application level, for example prefixing each message with a length (like done in TLS), ending each message with a newline (like done in SMTP) or similar. The recipient then need to read the data according to the message format, like first reading the length and then the given amount of bytes.

Comment: I will go with first approach, as I don't want to change the sender data. Now how can I recv until it returns empty? or I can recv until a new line charater is there? can you give me an example?

Comment: @NaggappanRamukannan: as for reading all see updated response. As for reading until end of line see [process socket data that ends with a line break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42987650/process-socket-data-that-ends-with-a-line-break).