# Parsing raw TCP data line by line in Python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, telnet, telnetlib

I'm getting stock market data via TCP. I'm trying to connect with Python to the broker, e.g. via Telnet (telnetlib) with read_eager() or via socket with socket.recv().

This is how the output looks like:

```
DE000XX6XP73;0.0000;2.44;G;2020-04-24;18:22:04.200'
';\r\nDE000XX9JX82;0.0000;0.0;G;2020-04-24;18:22:06.2'
'18;\r\nDE000XX9XXW3;0.0000;127.17;G;2020-04-24;18:22'
':21.954;\r\nDE000XX68XV1;0.0000;3.22;G;2020-04-24;18'
':21:11.517;\r\nDE000XX3H0X0;0.0000;1.81;G;2020-04-24'
```

and so on.

As you can see, this is one line:
`DE000XX6XP73;0.0000;2.44;G;2020-04-24;18:22:04.200;`

How can I parse each line? The TCP data stream never ends - it has no end of file and I need to process it in "real-time". The problem is that I'm getting "broken lines" most of the time, e.g.  `DE000XX3H0X0;0.0000;1.81;G;2020-04-24`

Comment: May help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42987650/process-socket-data-that-ends-with-a-line-break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find an own solution in Python which wasn't working as I expected. (Sync) Python was way too slow to handle those requests in real-time, it somehow stopped working after some time. I switched to async JS which is now working flawlessly.